# Bitbucket Jenkins plugin constructs wrong push URL

Tags: jenkins, plugins, bitbucket

We use Bitbucket server and want to trigger a Jenkins build whenever something is pushed to Bitbucket.

I tried to set up everything according to this page: 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin

So I created a Post Webhook in Bitbucket, pointing at the Jenkins Bitbucket plugin's endpoint.

Bitbucket successfully notifies the plugin when a push occurs. According to the Jenkins logs, the plugin then iterates over all jobs where "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" is checked, and tries to match that job's repo URL to the URL of the push that occurred.

So, if the repo URL is 
`https://jira.mycompany.com/stash/scm/PROJ/project.git`, the plugin tries to match it against 
`https://jira.mycompany.com/stash/PROJ/project`, which obviously fails.

As per official info from Atlassian, Bitbucket cannot be prevented from inserting the "/scm/" part in the path.

The corresponding code in the Bitbucket Jenkins plugin is in class `com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitbucketPayloadProcessor`:

```java
private void processWebhookPayloadBitBucketServer(JSONObject payload) {
    JSONObject repo = payload.getJSONObject("repository");
    String user = payload.getJSONObject("actor").getString("username");
    String url = "";
    if (repo.getJSONObject("links").getJSONArray("self").size() != 0) {
        try {
            URL pushHref = new URL(repo.getJSONObject("links").getJSONArray("self").getJSONObject(0).getString("href"));
            url = pushHref.toString().replaceFirst(new String("projects.*"), new String(repo.getString("fullName").toLowerCase()));
            String scm = repo.has("scmId") ? repo.getString("scmId") : "git";
            probe.triggerMatchingJobs(user, url, scm, payload.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("URL %s is malformed", url), e);
        }
    }
}
```

In the JSON payload that Bitbucket sends to the plugin, the actual checkout URL doesn't appear, only the link to the repository's Bitbucket page. The above method from the plugin appears to construct the checkout URL from that URL by removing everything after and including projects/ and adding the "full name" of the repo, resulting in the above wrong URL.

Official info from Atlassian is that Bitbucket cannot be prevented from adding the "scm" part to the checkout URL.

Is this a bug in the Jenkins plugin? If so, how can the plugin work for anyone?

Comment: Does iit work with SSH? I have set up web hooks with Bit Bucket and Jenkins and they worked ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the failure.

The issue is that the Bitbucket plugin for Jenkins **does** account for the `/scm` part in the path, **but only if it's the first part** after the host name.

If your Bitbucket server instance is configured not under its own domain but under a path of another service, matching the checkout URLs will fail.

Example:

`https://bitbucket.foobar.com/scm/PROJ/myproject.git` will work,

`https://jira.foobar.com/stash/scm/PROJ/myproject.git` will not work.

Someone who also had this problem has already created a fix for the plugin, the pull request for which is pending: [JENKINS-49177: Now removing first occurrence of /scm](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-plugin/pull/56)